# Address in use when creating macvlan networks for Docker

Tags: docker-networking

When I try to create macvlan networks in Docker, I get, well, see:

```bash
[Sat10@16:49:04][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉docker network create \
>   --attachable                               \
>   --driver macvlan                           \
>   --gateway 10.10.0.1                        \
>   --subnet  10.10.0.0/24                     \
>   --ipv6                                     \
>   --gateway 2001:XXXX:XXXX:0a00::            \
>   --subnet  2001:XXXX:XXXX:0a00::/120        \
>   --opt parent="z0b00" z0b00
Error response from daemon: failed to allocate gateway (2001:XXXX:XXXX:0a00::): Address already in use
[Sat10@16:49:04][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉
```

They are created on already-created VLAN interfaces (i.e; "`z0b00`"), which don't even have IP addressing enabled, just the L2 interface and that's it,  yet still (1.) it complains that the gateway address is already in use and (2.) what does it care if the gateway is occupied anyway!? It's not supposed to take it but make use of it, RELY on it (more like *relay to it* in this case), and not even *it*, the daemon, but the future guest containers. Correct? So what's up with that message?

<del>The address</del>, *NO address* has never existed on the host, the interface had its L3 settings turned off during its creation which is not done until things are applied. Only then it's created and brought up, so it cannot be like a lingering process either, I think. It really makes no sense.

This would be the corresponding network interface:

```bash
[Sat10@17:15:48][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉ip l sh z0a00
4: z0a00@ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:00:00:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[Sat10@17:16:27][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉ip a sh z0a00
4: z0a00@ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:00:00:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This syntax used to work before, how may I fix this? I figured maybe it's the IPv4/IPv6 gateway what it's referring to, being already defined in the other stack, then it would make sense. But I doubled checked adding `--help` to `docker network create` and found no way to distinguish between IPv4 and IPv6 for any of the common network properties. So that can't be it. The only sort of acknowledgement of the IPv6 stack is `--ipv6` which only means "enable IPv6", not an indicator of "from here on, these are IPv6 settings", though it kinda looks like it.

This syntax as I mentioned, I've used it before, it's in a text file that I can paste directly on the terminal and it deploys the full configuration for a host and deploys the containers in one step, I have versions of it, both for different host as well as in time. I searched the string "docker network create" and sure enough found them all; the syntax is exactly the same. I don't know what happened.

BTW, just before the command, I run `docker network rm $(docker network ls -q)` so there really are no conflicts. Docker is not actually "Docker" but the Moby Engine on Fedora 39, not to worry, I found this error in other distros too. It still applies. :(

Enchantments, dance around a dead cat; at this point all advice is good and I'll be grateful for it.

### UPDATE

I worked around it removing the IPv6 gateway, since it's macvlan I may be able to use this little snippet I found to get it to listen for router advertisements but nevertheless there were still things wrong where it shouldn't be anything wrong so I feel a little more not validated but at least more "it wasn't me", check out line 9 and around it:

```bash
1   [Sat10@19:42:49][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉docker network create \
2   >   --attachable                              \
3   >   --driver macvlan                          \
4   >   --gateway 10.9.0.1                        \
5   >   --subnet  10.9.0.0/24                     \
6   >   --ipv6                                    \
7   >   --subnet  2001:XXXX:XXXX:0900::/120       \
8   >   --opt parent="z0900" z0900
9   Error response from daemon: invalid subinterface vlan name z0900, example formatting is eth0.10
10  [Sat10@19:42:49][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉docker network create \
11  >   --attachable                              \
12  >   --driver macvlan                          \
13  >   --gateway 10.10.0.1                       \
14  >   --subnet  10.10.0.0/24                    \
15  >   --ipv6                                    \
16  >   --subnet  2001:XXXX:XXXX:0a00::/120       \
17  >   --opt parent="z0a00" z0a00
18  0d3d242ee3d7567aeef4fa68a0ad2408d66caea337c262b6cffdbe4adf2848d0
19  [Sat10@19:42:50][root@nudisco:/opt/mountdog] #〉docker network create \
```

> Other than the second and third hextets of the IPv6 addresses, the code is a verbatim copy from the CLI.

Comment: Can you do `ip -6 addr`(and maybe grep for that address)